# В bash для windows на команду pip отвечает команда не найдена. Ввожу python -m pip list ответ Python. На все попытки выполнить код отвечает Python

Tags: python, pip, git-bash

artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ pip list
bash: pip: command not found

artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ pip list | wc -l
bash: pip: command not found
0

artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ python -m pip list
Python
artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ python

artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ python -m pip list | wc -l
Python 0

artur@art MINGW64 ~
$ python count_words1.py
Python

Comment: "На все попытки выполнить код отвечает Python" - удалите Python, установленный через магазин microsoft, установите с сайта https://python.org